# Cannot connect to Azure DevOps repository from Visual Studio using Microsoft Account already added to Organization Project

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-account

My work email address was added to a project in Azure DevOps in an Organization by my Client. At that time I did not have a Microsoft account. So whenever I tried to login into Azure DevOps through the URL, "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}" Azure sent me a one-time code through which I could log in. However, the client expected me to pull code into Visual Studio using the Azure DevOps server URL. But that requires a Microsoft Account which I did not have.

So I contacted my administrator who created a Microsoft Account for me using my work email address. My client then removed and added my account back to the project in the Azure DevOps Organization. But still, when I go to log into Azure DevOps, it is still sending me a one-time passcode. In Visual Studio, I managed to login using my Microsoft Account but when I try to connect to my client's project using the Azure DevOps server URL, I get the message "To access an Azure DevOps account, log in using the picker above." This despite the fact that I am already logged in using the Microsoft Account and I have selected it from the list "Showing hosted repositories for".

I have a done a lot of research for this scenario but did not find any answers. Here are some pointers

- When I go to https://aex.dev.azure.com/ when I am logged into my
  Microsoft account, it shows me as a member of my client's Azure
  DevOps Organizations
- When I go to https://myaccount.microsoft.com/organizations, I cannot
  see my client's organization in the list of organizations.
- To login to [https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}](https://dev.azure.com/%7BOrganization%7D/%7BProject%7D), when I
  use my Microsoft Account, it sends me a passcode. And once logged in,
  when I click on "View Account" from Account Manager (located at the
  top right extreme in the website), I get "Microsoft Account does not
  exist".

Comment: When you connect the Azure Repo in VS, is there any error message when you log in the azure devops ?